# select minimum data for bunch of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, minimum

I have this table :

[image]

I want to find minimum date_time value for each bunch of colored record, that is, the result of the table will be this table.

[image]

Which SQL command is needed?

Comment: Gaps and island first then windowed function/group by. Easy to achieve if you provide https://dbfiddle.uk data.

Comment: You show photos of Excel. Do you have actual SQL tables? If so, please show the table definition of the table. Please also show the data you have as text. For SQL, the query would be `select Strand1, min(DATE_TIME) from mytable group by Strand1`

Comment: @Corion Won't work you have multiple `0` groups

Comment: First you need to get subgrouping per each continuous `000`,`111`,`000`,... then you could use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @lukaszSzozda: Aaah, yes, now I understand the "colouring". Yes, a window function is adequate then ;)

Comment: @mehdihallaj . . . Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort-of a gaps-and-islands problem.  But  the simplest way to think of it is as a simple `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(t.strand1) over (order by t.date_time) as prev_strand1
      from t
     ) t
where prev_strand1 is null or prev_strand1 <> strand1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find minimum of date_time value for each whatever value of Strand1

```
select Strand1, min(DATE_TIME) from mytable where Strand1 = whatever group by Strand1
```

Comment: I don't want group all 0 or 1 srtrand1 data.with your command we will give 1 record.

Comment: You want minimum date_time So you are going to have one number for each record.